# How can I call my model from controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am attempting to call my model from my controller, but get errors. The error is on

`new UserModels(id, searchcriteria);`

and states that

`UserModels does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments.`

Any ideas?

Controller/Action:

```
    public ActionResult ID(string id)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Customer Information";

        string searchcriteria = "userid";

        UserModels model = new UserModels(id, searchcriteria);

        return View();
    }
```

Model:

```
public class UserModels
    {
        public UserData user { get; set; }

        public string firstname { get; set; }
        public string lastname { get; set; }

        public string searchvalue {get; set; }
        public string searchcriteria { get; set; }


        public List<UserData> UserModel(string id, string searchcriteria) 
        {
            SSO_Methods sso = new SSO_Methods();

            List<UserData> userObject = sso.GetUserObject(id, searchcriteria);

            return userObject;

        }





    }
```

Comment: The method that you used is not a constructor... It is just another method in UserModels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Constructors in c# cannot return anything.

Your code would need to be

```
public UserModels(string id, string searchcriteria) 
{
    // your code here
}
```

Then if you are wanting to return a list, add in

```
public List<UserData> GetUserModels(string id, string searchcriteria) 
{    
    SSO_Methods sso = new SSO_Methods();
    List<UserData> userObject = sso.GetUserObject(id, searchcriteria);
    return userObject;
}
```

Comment: Well they return an instance of the type :P  But yes no explicit return statement.

Comment: Tim, how would I call GetUserModels from the Controller?

Comment: @TreyCopeland it seems to me that your `GetUserModels` method should be in a repository class.

Comment: @TreyCopeland Just call `var item =  model.GetUserModels(id, searchcriteria);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a constructor which has 2 parameters. To create a constructor you have to write something like this: `[public, private, protected, internal] [classname]([parameters])`. 
So just change this: `public List<UserData> UserModel(string id, string searchcriteria)`
To `public UserModel(string id, string searchcriteria)`. Notice that a constructor must not return anything. Use properties instead of your return type.